# Confusion regarding conservation of ME

Tags: forces, energy

Lets say we have an object(system) at a height h above ground(taking ground to be a reference point) and then we release the body.
Work done by gravity as it falls down (only force acting in this case) is mgh(mg and h(as in displacement)in same direction).
mgh= change in KE(writing as ^KE)--->(work energy theorem)

now as far as i know change in U(^U) is negative of the work done by the conservative force, which here is gravity.Thus we can say ,
mgh=^KE--->-(^U)=^KE--->
^KE+^U=0---->^ME(mechanical energy)=0

But isn't  work done by external force(mgh on body)  change in mechanical energy?
so isn't mgh=^ME??
Iam considering the body to be a system so gravity is external force here.

I know the first case is right but cant seem to convincingly disprove the second to myself, i am sure i have some misconceptions about conservative forces and external forces

Comment: What do you call ME, KE is an ME, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry, by ME here i mean the total mechanical energy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question About Potential Energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321288/).  It is one of many such posts. The confusion starts by the system under consideration not being defined. Choose either object alone as the system or object **and** Earth. Potential energy cannot be defined for the object alone system.

Comment: now it makes sense, i should have read some of the posts here before ig.Thank Yous o much